# How to make file template in intellij idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

As you can see from the title I'm trying to create a plugin for android studio with intellij-idea which generate Java and xml files, but I don't know how because I never find any document or tutorial about this subject so how to make intellij-idea plugin that create files